# git merge stopped working

Tags: git

I was using the following procedure for a while:

```
git fetch origin master  
git merge origin/master  
git push --dry-run origin master  
git push origin master
```

Now this has stopped working and produces this error

```
To git@example.com:company/project/admin.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@example.com:company/project/admin.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

and now only git pull works and not fetch and merge.

Why would this happen? It is also happening to other developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're doing:

```
git fetch origin master
```

... which updates `FETCH_HEAD` with `master` from `origin`, but *doesn't* update the remote-tracking branch `origin/master`.

You probably want to do:

```
git fetch origin
```

... instead, which will update all remote-tracking branches from `origin`, including `origin/master`.

This is explained in the documentation for `git fetch`, but I think it's fair to say that this is confusing for a lot of people...